# как отключить владение файлами на windows

Tags: файлы, windows-10

недавно появился жёлтый замок в верхнем правом углу на практически всех файлах и папках. хочу отключить, а не знаю где.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перелогиньтесь другим пользователем.

Comment: хорошо, помогло